# reactjs: render a component on top of fullcalendar

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fullcalendar

I was trying to render a pop up on eventclick but for some reason it does not trigger the popup. But when I console.log or use alert It works, I tried bootstrap and ant-d but both of them don't even load.

imports

```
import { notification, Menu, Dropdown, Popconfirm, Button } from 'antd'
import { DownOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
```

the render component

```
<FullCalendar
        timeZone={tz}
        plugins={[timeGridPlugin, dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, momentTimezonePlugin]}
        initialView="timeGridWeek"
        headerToolbar={{
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
        }}
        editable
        selectable
        weekends
        events={schedule}
        select={handleDateSelect}
        eventClick={handleEventClick}
        eventChange={function(){}}
        eventRemove={function(){}}
        */
      />
```

and here are the handler functions

```
  const showPopconfirm = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  };
  const handleOk = () => {
    setConfirmLoading(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setVisible(false)
      setConfirmLoading(false)
    }, 2000)

    console.log('handleOKcomplete')
  }

  const handleCancel = () => {
    console.log('Clicked cancel button')
    setVisible(false)
  }
  const loadpopup = () => (
    <Popconfirm
      title="Title"
      visible={visible}
      onConfirm={handleOk}
      okButtonProps={{ loading: confirmLoading }}
      onCancel={handleCancel}
    >
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showPopconfirm}>
        Open Popconfirm with async logic
      </Button>
    </Popconfirm>
    )
```

and here's a working component from antd

https://codesandbox.io/s/2dk19?file=/index.js:178-230

Comment: At a guess maybe it's a z-index issue?

Comment: I have tried that as well it is still not working, My component was not even showing in the html inspect. So you think this is the right way to implement it or should I be using some other calendar props? btw I've been reading your other answers related to Fullcalendar and it's been a great help. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Thanks, glad the info was useful. I don't anything at all about React however so I can't comment on your specific implementation. I only work in vanilla JS.

Comment: I see, anyways thank you for the suggestion! :)